# Coin Flipping Expected Value

Tags: probability, expectation

Find the expected value for the number of flips you'll need to make in order to see the pattern TXT, where T is tails, and X is either heads or tails.

I tried conditioning on the coin flips (e.g. TXT, TXH, H) but I got an incorrect answer of 8. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you had `TTH` happening with probability $\frac{1}{8}$ and giving $E+3$ flips, where $E$ is the expected value of the required number of flips. This is wrong, because we don't have to restart when we get `TTH`.

`TTH` leads to `TTHT` and `TTHH` with equal probability. `TTHT` gives length $4$; `TTHH` gives length $E+4$.

In summary:
\begin{align}
H: &\frac{1}{2} & (E+1) \\
THT: &\frac{1}{8} & 3 \\
THH: &\frac{1}{8} & (E+3) \\
TTT: &\frac{1}{8} & 3 \\
TTHT: &\frac{1}{16} & 4 \\
TTHH: &\frac{1}{16} & (E+4)
\end{align}

Summing them all up and equating to $E$, and solving for $E$ gives $E = \frac{34}{5}$.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the expected value for the number of flips until TT and then add 1 because X can just be ignored otherwise.